# git log format: shift commit body X columns to the right

Tags: git, format

I'm using the following custom log format to view my commits:

Command: `git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h %<(8,trunc)%aN %Cgreen%s %+b"`

```
3758d35 Daniel   This commit does nothing 
You really should remove it before commiting.

    1. This is a line
    2. This is another line

a191c2b Daniel   Viral helvetica lomo, typewriter fashion axe 
814a6a9 John     Umami pork belly pickled, fanny pack yr keffiyeh fap YOLO
d5e130e Daniel   Cardigan raw denim banjo
f7107d8 Daniel   90's ramps pinterest, craft beer blue bottle
```

It works great except **I'd like the commit body to be aligned with the commit title**. Is it possible to achieve using only git?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `%w(<your max line width>,<first line indent>,<second line indent>)` in front of the message body, e.g.

`%w(64,16,16)%b`

From [pretty format documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emwltwgtlti1gtlti2gtem):

> `%w([<w>[,<i1>[,<i2>]]])`
>
> switch line wrapping, like the -w option of `git-shortlog[1]`.

And from [shortlog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#Documentation/git-shortlog.txt--wltwidthgtltindent1gtltindent2gt):

> `-w[<width>[,<indent1>[,<indent2>]]]`
>
> Linewrap the output by wrapping each line at width. The first line of each entry is indented by indent1 spaces, and the second and subsequent lines are indented by indent2 spaces. width, indent1, and indent2 default to 76, 6 and 9 respectively.
>
> If width is 0 (zero) then indent the lines of the output without wrapping them.

Can't say how to drop the trailing newline, but I guess it might be possible with some additional format specifier. There are options for stripping preceding newlines from a placeholder, but no similar option for a trailing one.

Comment: Great answer! I've implemented the line-wrapping like you suggested: `git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h %<(8,trunc)%aN %Cgreen%s %n%w(80,17,17)%-b"`. I'll mark this as the solution and post another question for the ending newline. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Daniel I couldn't find your question about stripping the ending newline. Did you figure it out? What was the solution?

Comment: @Dan Li https://stackoverflow.com/q/58016135/3018229