# git log --pretty=%b but without newline after the body

Tags: git

It’s possible to customize the formatting of git log with [`--pretty`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting). However I can’t find a way to display the body without trailing newline. Is it possible?

I would like to be able to display my log like this:

```
dc121234 Add some stuff
2349823f Update things
23498fe2 Add bugs
It’s important to add bug to your code
12398aab Clear thing
```

With `--pretty="%h %s%+b"` I’m nearly there, but this is what I got:

```
dc121234 Add some stuff
2349823f Update things
23498fe2 Add bugs
It’s important to add bug to your code

12398aab Clear thing
```

And if I want to add some more empty space with `--pretty="%h %s%+b%n"` (I added a `%n` between `%s` and `%b`), I get an unwanted double newline after the multilines commit message:

```
dc121234 Add some stuff

2349823f Update things

23498fe2 Add bugs
It’s important to add bug to your code


12398aab Clear thing
```

Is there a way to remove the extra trailing newline added after the `%b`?

Comment: Did you try [`%B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emBem) instead of `%s%+b`? (Edit : tried it, no better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`--pretty=` defaults to `tformat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---prettyltformatgt), with terminator newlines. `--pretty=format:%h\ %s%n%b%-C` won't add an extra newline at the end and will eat all the trailing newlines on the body.

Comment: This doesn’t work either. `%B` adds an empty line *before* the body which is not something I want either.

Comment: And the only difference that I see with `tformat` is an extra empty line at the end of the output (both with `%B` and `%s%+b`).

Comment: It works now. I thought that extra newline at the end of the output was what you were referring to and didn't notice the subject-to-body separator stripping. The `%-C` newline eater at the end does what you really want.

Comment: Awesome! How did you discovered it, I can’t find it in the doc. I thought that %C was only for colors.

Comment: It's the `-` modifier on the placeholder I was after, you found `+`, insert a space only if the placeholder expands to something, here you wanted `-`, eat existing trailing newlines only if this placeholder expands to nothing. `C` is one of the placeholders that "affect the formatting of later placeholders", I'd been using  `%-gd` since reflog selectors expand to nothing on logs not using `--walk-reflogs`, I can't find the comment thread on SO where someone else found `%-C`, it was years ago now.

Comment: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016135/format-string-for-consistent-separation-between-entries-output-by-git-log-pre).