# Recreate "medium" format to use in git log

Tags: git

I'm trying to recreate the "[medium](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats)" format to use as the `--format` argument `git log`, with just one difference: I want to display the *committer* date, rather than the author date.

My attempt so far looks like this:

```
commit %H
Author: %aN <%aE>
Date:   %cD

    %s

    %b
```

Several things are missing or not just right, though, and I'm not sure how to fix them:

1. I can't seem to turn on coloring
2. Only the first line of the body of the commit (%b) is indented by one tab, not the following ones.
3. I can't see how to insert tags and other useful information in the first line (e.g. `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `%C(auto)` in your format
2. I'm unsure you can do that. `%B` instead of `%b` would use full unwrapped body, which you could manipulate afterwards?
3. use `--decorate` as a flag for the `log` command

--- Credit to OP for the following, see comments below ---

2. Using `%w` can recreate the message body padding.

Final resulting command:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)commit %H%d%nAuthor: %aN <%aE>%nDate: %cD%n%n %s%n%n%w(80,4,4)%b" --decorate=auto
```

Comment: Almost there! So, 1. is spot on. 3. is right, but I need a `%d` next to `%H`. 2. I wonder if it's a weird combination of `%w` and `%>` that will do the trick. So far the result is as follows: `git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)commit %H%d%nAuthor:     %aN <%aE>%nDate:        %cD%n%n %s%n%n    %b" --decorate=auto`. Feel free to update your text with the above line and I'll mark it as the the answer.

Comment: @Jir Well done, I've been wondering for the 2. for a while but you've been quicker! :-)

Comment: Good team work! :) Also, credit where it's due, the `%w` part comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807182/222529).